# GML to KML Files: Viewing GML document on Google Earth

Tags: kml

Can you explain to me how to convert GML file to KML file?

I work in real estate development. Before we go and have a look at a place, we would like to make sure that the place is suitable for development using Google Earth.

I have got these data from Land Registry that comes in gml format and want to view them on Google Earth which, I understand, uses kml format. How do I convert gml to kml file?

Guys, I am not a computer developer and my computing skills are limited to spreadsheet modelling. Can you take me through the conversion step by step without getting into programming?

I appreciate your help. Land Registry IT people have been very unhelpful. My company's IT department has also been very unhelpful.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would recommend the [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) commands, but since you say you are not so experienced I think the most suitable solution for you would be [this online geodata conversion service](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/).

I did not try it (because I use GIS Tools all day), and its only in Test stadium, but as far as I can see it should work.

Just:

1. ZIP the GML
2. Upload it there (under run vector converter)
3. Select KML as destination Format
4. Download ready KML File

If it does not work for you, let us know. I will teach you the magic of GDAL/OGR then ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just as I was about to give up, I found this conversion website http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/index.php that works for the Land Registry data I have got. The size of the file is huge, 100,000KB (again I don't know how big this actually is - I think the file is big because it takes long time to open on Google Earth). Is there any way to simplify it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Not very easily, but you can open the KML with a simple TextEditor (Notepad will have troubles with huge Files, so download and use "Notepad++"), and divide it into multiple files. When you open it, you'll see a lot of text (thats XML btw.). Every item (parcel?) of your land registry data starts with `<Placemark>` and ends with `</Placemark>`. You can savely cut and copy these items to another textfile, to simply divide the amount of parcels per File. Every single one then loads faster for sure.

Comment: Better: Learn some GIS Basics and use a Viewer like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) where you can load the GML directly, edit it, dont have to worry much about how large the File is, query it, Overlay it with other data and analyze it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will learn the GIS basics when I have the time.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded GQIS and uploaded the files that I downloaded from Land Registry, but I can't edit the attribute table. The button is grayed out. Do you know why this is happening? I have got table manager installed.

Comment: I think I got it. It can only edit ESRI shape files, can't it? These softwares are now putting me off real estate investment...Thanks for the help.